# How to force int as string in prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm working on syncing two PostgreSQL databases using a PHP script. I am not able to query the entire table so I have to use an id column to grab records in batches.

The id column is a string column, not numeric. However, there are numerical ids in the column. This is where I'm having an issue.

When I prepare the SQL statement in PHP, when I happen to get an id that is numeric, when I bind it to the statement, it doesn't put quotes around the value because it thinks its an int, not a string.

How do I force it to be a string and always put single quotes around the id??

If I put the quotes around the ? in the query it treats it as text and the parameter doesn't get bound to the statement.

As you can see in the code I also tried casting the $start variable as a string. $start contains the starting id.

Here is the code:

```
$sql = "select id from properties where id > ? order by id limit ?";
$params = [(string) $start, 50000];
$rows = $this->wolfnet->select($sql, $params);
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something postgresql specific, but if `id` is a string, you should probably not be using `id > ?`. How do you even know that newly inserted `id` gets processed at the end when you use the `id` like that? It might not get processed ever.

Comment: It does work. If you put single quotes around the id field and run the query via an SQL client (i.e. HeidiSQL) the query works and gets the next id in line. I just can't get the prepared statement to put single quotes around the id value.

Comment: you can type parameters in SQL: `WHERE id > ?::text`